# Cannot access variables defined in webpack after build from client

Tags: javascript, webpack, chart.js

This may be a novice question, however after researching other questions on the platform and delving through the Webpack documentation I have seen many ways people have attempted this. I have seen nothing really which I can take to apply to my problem.

I wish to use Chart.js using a bundler (Webpack). Creating this file I store the instance in a variable. See the below code snippets to follow along.

`src/index.js`

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const myFirstChart = new Chart("test", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
    }
})
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    }
}
```

`index.ejs`

```
<script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
```

The chart loads no problem after building using the `webpack` command. The issue I am facing is that I would assume that I could access the instance of this chart in my console as I wish to do some updating of data after initialization of the chart.

I would expect to be able to access the variable `myFirstChart` as I would if Chart.js was a CDN or loaded directly.

Is this something that I have maybe overlooked within the documentation of either Chart.js or Webpack 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of webpack is to process modules, and the whole point of modules is to **not pollute** the global name space. If another file of JS code needs access to a variable, `export` it where it is created, and `import` it in that other file.

Any variables defined in modules are module-scoped only; it is widely considered bad practice to make use of the global namespace at all.

If you absolutely need that (and you're most probably doing it wrong if that is the case), add `window.myFirstChart = myFirstChart;` in your `index.js` file:

```js
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const myFirstChart = new Chart("test", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
    }
})
window.myFirstChart = myFirstChart;
```

Any variable you need to be available globally you explicitly need to publish by attaching it to the global `window` object (which is where the browser looks them up unless they're defined anywhere more local as to where you're trying to access it).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I may have been over complicating what I was trying to do when, I can ideally perform all the tasks within module files. I will take this feedback also onboard for the future.